# Graph Customization in python

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

currently I have a program that takes data and makes a histogram out of it, I know how to change the labels and stuff, but is there a way to make x-axis display the number range more frequently (badly worded I'll just give an example):so right now on the x-axis is shows the number values in increments of 5, but how can I make it show up in like increments of 2 or 1 or 3.

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

l=[]
with open("testdata") as f:
    line = f.next()
    f.next()# skip headers
    nat = int(line.split()[
    print nat

    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            l.append(map(float,line.split()[1:]))  

    b = 0
    a = 1

distances = []
for b in range(53):
    for a in range(b+1,54):
        vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
        vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])

        x = vector1
        y = vector2
            vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))

        dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))

        dp = dotProduct**.5

        distances.append(dp)

    num_bins = 200 # <- number of bins for the histogram
(n, bins, patches) = plt.hist(distances, num_bins) 
plt.title('Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label_positions = np.arange(start, end, step, endpoint=True)
plt.xticks(label_positions)
```

Comment: By the way is there also a way to make the actual value of each bar appear on top of the bars?

Comment: you might visit the matplotlib example http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html